# Enable ST2 PHP shorthand tag autocomplete in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

So, in Sublime I can type `foreach`, hit tab, and get this:

```
<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value): ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

How can I enable this for PhpStorm? I was convinced that in my Sublime installation, it was handled by Emmet, but after installing it I did not get this functionality in PhpStorm. Is it available somehow?

Comment: Check out https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/auto-completing-code.html and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7276

Answer (score 1):

Check "An introduction to Live Templates" out please
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/54339108

Comment: Ill be a bit cheeky, is there somewhere a premade templates, for shorthand PHP constructs?

Comment: Yes, of course. Try to: 
1. type "fore".
2. cmd+j .
3. select template and next enter.

does it work to u?